# reallocating boost::shared_array

Tags: c++, boost, realloc

I have a shared_array:
boost::shared_array myarr(new char[m_length]);

I would like to reallocate the array. I thought of creating a new shared_array with the wanted size and using the swap boost method but this will copy the referance count as well.
Do you have another idea?

```
//new_length>m_length
void func(boost::shared_array<char> &myarr,int new_length)
{
       boost::shared_array<char> new_arr(new char[new_length]);
       myarr.swap(new_arr);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just instead use a `boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<char> >`? Let the standard library handle resizing.

(In fact, depending on why you were using shared_array in the first place, you might well get away with just using a std::vector, and passing it around by reference carefully.)

Comment: I want to make sure the content is not copied by value. That is why I use the shared_array. How is the performance of boost::sharerd_ptr::vector<char>

Comment: A shared_ptr to a vector will probably create an extra level of indirection, but otherwise everything is as neat as possible - the data is contiguous. If all you want to do is prevent copying, you could just create a class inheriting from boost::noncopyable, have a std::vector member, and expose the desired interface.

Answer (score 1):

boost::shared_array::reset should do the trick

```
myarr.reset(new char[new_length]);
```

boost::shared_array::reset deletes the old allocated array, swapping it with the newly allocated one.

Edit: Ignore this answer, it doesn't solve his problem

Comment: Does it keep the reference counter of the old one? Does it copy the value of the array to the new one? I need the same value but in a bigger size array.